# Porting software to Panasonic Viera

Tags: javascript, html, television

We are porting the existing HTML/JavaScript/CSS application to the Panasonic platform.  In the application we use the JavaScript to generate HTML and the CSS to style the app.

The Panasonic Viera Connect platform programming language is JavaScript, but is “Non-browser JavaScript Engine”, which means that except of the engine classes we need to rewrite the whole UI rendering part, since they have for that their own API.

Is rewriting the application only way? Does anybody other experience?

Comment: Seems like you don't have any choice, do you?

Comment: That's what I am asking... We are partly done on this, but more we are doing less i like it, so I am looking for other possibilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

rewrite application is the only way.
I am developing video library for Central European Media Enterprises last 4 months.

http://developer.vieraconnect.com/ - here is registration portal (free or paid) with some starting examples and documentation.

Company has small deal with Panasonic , so I have access to Panasonic forum, where I can discuss issues with Panasonic developers guys.

Viera Connect Developers Application is only way how to do this. It is available on Market.

Source of application you can store in local network or contact Panasonic.

But you can use some JS libraries ( server API control :)

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - we come to the same conclusion meanwhile. While LG, Samsung, Philips and other platforms are more or less compatible (but detailed and log testing is necessary), the Panasonic is somehow an exception out of that... Good luck with your development.

Comment: We also develop this app for LG and Samsung, and there is 95% common code :)
First version of app is already deployed to Czech Republic market :)
Still, if you need anything else about Panasonic, just ask me.

Comment: @JosefZajac which one is best for Panasonic application development Ajax CE or html5 OR if you have any tutorial or examples, it will be more helpful thanks.

Comment: Hi, We are doing HTML5 only. I am even not sure 2013 TV models will support Ajax CE.